# SUMIFS with Arrayformula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, sumifs

I need to do a SUMIFS formula in a column with 2 conditions.
However, when there is a new data pull, the formula would not get expanded to the bottom.
Hence, I thought it might be a good idea to use an Arrayformula instead, but as you know SUMIFS do not work in Arrayformulas.

The data that should be summed is as follows:

Column D: there is the value to be summmed
Column M: there is an ID
Column AF: there is another condition (product group)

The 2 conditions could match on several rows.
The SUM I'd like to show is always the TOTAL (not e.g. a running sum).
Hence, the total amount of a product group for a certain Deal ID.

Do you have an idea how I could implement this?

Thanks a lot
Stefan

Comment: You can utilize `MAP()` function to expand formula to till last data cell. Share few sample data.

Comment: Maybe another way is to use a pivot or a group by on two variables within a query.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   SUM(
     D:D*(M:M=id)*(AF:AF=group)
   ) 
 )
```

- `id` and `group` could be cell references or values.
- Sheets interprets `TRUE=1` and `FALSE=0`
- If any of the 3 factors is zero (or FALSE) then the product for that row is zero.

##### Example Rows, Conditional Behavior

```
10*TRUE*TRUE   =10*1*1 =10
10*FALSE*TRUE  =10*0*1 = 0
10*TRUE*FALSE  =10*1*0 = 0 
 0*TRUE*TRUE   = 0*1*1 = 0
```